# Hardware interrupt handler in C++

Tags: c++, assembly

I wrote this class to use a C++ function as hardware interrupt handler. The idea is to have a single entry point where I can switch stacks, and call a chain of `std::function` objects to handle the interrupt.

It works... but I think it's a pretty ugly hack. Is there anything I could improve here?

```
class __attribute__((packed)) interrupt_wrapper
{
    using function_ptr = void(*)(unsigned);
    unsigned int_vector;            // [eax-0x1C]
    selector ds;                    // [eax-0x18]
    selector es;                    // [eax-0x16]
    selector fs;                    // [eax-0x14]
    selector gs;                    // [eax-0x12]
    function_ptr entry_point;       // [eax-0x10]
    std::array<byte, 0x40> code;    // [eax-0x0C]

public:
    interrupt_wrapper(unsigned vec, function_ptr f) : int_vector(vec), entry_point(f)
    {
        byte* start;
        std::size_t size;
        asm volatile (
            ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
            "jmp interrupt_wrapper_end%=;"
            // --- \/\/\/\/\/\/ --- //
            "interrupt_wrapper_begin%=:;"   // On entry, the only known register is CS.
            "push ds; push es; push fs; push gs; pusha;"    // 7 bytes
            "call get_eip%=;"  // call near/relative (E8)   // 5 bytes
            "get_eip%=: pop eax;"           // Pop EIP into EAX and use it to find our variables
            "mov ds, cs:[eax-0x18];"        // Restore segment registers
            "mov es, cs:[eax-0x16];"        
            "mov fs, cs:[eax-0x14];"
            "mov gs, cs:[eax-0x12];"
            "push cs:[eax-0x1C];"           // Pass our interrupt number along
            "call cs:[eax-0x10];"           // Call the entry point
            "add esp, 4;"
            "popa; pop gs; pop fs; pop es; pop ds;"
            "sti;"                          // IRET is not guaranteed to set the interrupt flag.
            "iret;"
            "interrupt_wrapper_end%=:;"
            // --- /\/\/\/\/\/\ --- //
            "mov %0, offset interrupt_wrapper_begin%=;"
            "mov %1, offset interrupt_wrapper_end%=;"
            "sub %1, %0;"                   // size = end - begin
            ".att_syntax prefix"
            : "=r" (start)
            , "=r" (size));
        assert(size <= code.size());

        auto* ptr = memory_descriptor(get_cs(), start).get_ptr<byte>(); // Get near pointer to cs:[start]
        std::copy_n(ptr, size, code.data());

        asm volatile (
            ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
            "mov ax, ds;"
            "mov bx, es;"
            "mov cx, fs;"
            "mov dx, gs;"
            ".att_syntax prefix"
            : "=a" (ds)
            , "=b" (es)
            , "=c" (fs)
            , "=d" (gs));
    }

    auto get_ptr(selector cs) { return far_ptr32 { cs, reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(code.data()) }; }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're missing some pieces, such as the `memory_descriptor` and `far_ptr32` classes and `get_cs` function and I guessed at the definitions of `selector` and `byte`, but with that said, here's what I found that may help you improve your code.

### Make the constructor `noexcept`

It's unlikely that an exception within the constructor would be a welcome event.  For that reason, your constructor should be declared `noexcept`.

### Make `function_ptr` `noexcept`

For similar reasons, I'd suggest making `function_ptr` also `noexcept`:

```
using function_ptr = void(*)(unsigned) noexcept;
```

### Be careful with interrupt flags

Instead of disabling all interrupts using `sti`, it might be better to restore the interrupt flag to whatever it had been.  Although the interrupt could not have been called by *hardware* if the interrupt flag had been reset (that is, interrupts disabled) but it's not uncommon to chain interrupts by having one hardware interrupt chain to another via explicit call.  In that circumstance, the hardware flag should not be re-enabled lest the interrupt chain be incorrectly interrupted.

Comment: Thanks, these are some good points. I didn't know you could mark C-style function pointers as `noexcept`, too.  The `memory_descriptor` and `far_ptr32` classes are not really relevant in this question, I think. The first describes a linear memory region and provides near-pointer access, among other things. the second describes a far-pointer (selector and offset). `byte` and `selector` are, as you may have guessed, aliases for `std::uint8_t` and `std::uint16_t`, respectively.

Comment: I do still think it's a good idea to set the interrupt flag unconditionally on return. Think about it: if interrupts were disabled, the interrupt handler would have never been called in the first place.

Comment: The interrupt handler would not have been called *by a hardware interrupt* but there is still the possibility that it was invoked (e.g. by interrupt chaining) by software.

Comment: If it was chained from another hardware interrupt, and mine is the last in the chain, wouldn't my handler have the responsibility to set the flag again? I just looked it up and the [OS documentation](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/dpmi/ch4.4.2.html) also recommends to `sti` before `iret`. This doesn't really improve my headache...

Comment: It's not clear why you'd assume your interrupt is the last in the chain.  Interrupt chaining doesn't necessarily require the participation of the individual interrupt handlers.

Comment: DPMI is a fairly simple OS (if you could even call it that), I don't think it would chain automatically. But then, I'm not really sure either.

Comment: The combination of C++11 and DPMI seems a strange anachronism...

Comment: Which makes this project all the more fun :)